# usb boot flash drive with extra space on it. Can it be used?

Tags: live-usb

I have a bootable usb drive with extra space on it. Do i have to create another partition to use the extra space, or can i put everything i want on the device into one folder and copy it to the drive right along with all the installation files?  Would this mess up my multi-boot operation or installation if I were to add a large folder with all my other 'stuff' to it?
By the way, this is for a pc and using windows files.

Comment: If I get you right, you want to use the bootable usb for other things ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the partition table and file system in the USB drive. Do I understand correctly that you have a multiboot system in it? In that case I am almost sure that you can edit the partition table, either change the size of one of the partitions or add a partition. This should be done, when you have booted from another drive. You can use **gparted** to do it (it comes with the Ubuntu iso files).

But if you have a live-only boot drive with an ISO 9660 file system, the partition table is read-only. In this case you can create a new persistent live USB boot system into it. [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) can create such a system with one partition for persistence, 'casper-rw', and another partition for storage and communication with Windows, 'usbdata'.

If you post the output of the following command lines, I can give better advice,

```
sudo parted -ls
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

Comment: well it's just a regular usb flash drive that i made into a multi-boot drive so i can install any version of windows from it.  My question is can I place a folder in there (containing other stuff i want stored) among all the other files the multiboot software created for me?

Comment: will the multi-bootable software on the drive still work right if i add a folder among them containing my data?

Comment: Yes, I think so (I am almost sure). It is not very risky, if it does not work, you can remove that folder.  Creating partitions is more risky, but this is probably not necessary.

Comment: yes, I was kinda thinking the same thing. Creating partitions should be unnecessary as long as I keep all my files neat and in just one folder in there.  thanks for the advice.. i could always remove the folder if it messes up and then worry about making another partition

Comment: That is a good idea. Good luck :-)